# Rspec for presence validation not working in Rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

#### Model Todo

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, :created_by, presence: true
end
```

#### RSpecs

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Todo, type: :model do
  it { should have_many(:items).dependent(:destroy) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:created_by) }
end
```

When i run the command `bundle exec rspec`, i see:

```
Finished in 1.82 seconds (files took 0.97238 seconds to load)
5 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/todo_spec.rb:8 # Todo should validate that :title cannot be empty/falsy
rspec ./spec/models/todo_spec.rb:9 # Todo should validate that :created_by cannot be empty/falsy
```

Can anyone explain why is it failing?

Comment: You have a typo in the Todo model, `validates :title, :created_by, presence: true` missing comma.

Comment: Already fix the comma but thats not the mistake

Comment: Your output says "5 examples", but i see only 3 in your code.

Comment: 3 from one model and 2 from this, but the problem is on this model

Comment: Please read the [issue in shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/951)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the issue in [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/951). You need to add to your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel, type: :model)
  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord, type: :model)
end
```